# Identifying user info from session state

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, session-state, session-storage

Is there a way to know if a user is a first time visitor on a page via `HttpSessionStateBase` class?

Or is there a more secure alternate approach by utilizing **session-cookies**?

Comment: first time during the current session, or first time ever?

Comment: @ADyson first time ever

Comment: Then logically the answer is no, because session data only relates to the current session. You'd be better keeping a log of visits by that user (assuming your users have to authenticate it wouldn't be too hard. Tracking anonymous users is a lot harder)

Comment: @ADyson any other server side solution involving session cookies?

Comment: Well you could possibly stick some other cookie on the machine (session cookies expire with the session - as I already explained, using sessions is not a good fit here). But then if the same user logs in from another device (or even another browser on the same device) onto the same page, do you want to count them as a first-time visitor again? Like I said, a lot depends on whether these "users" are logged  in or not, but you didn't mention that.

Comment: @ADyson yes, other browser, other machine would be a first time too.

Comment: Maybe just a regular cookie, with no expiry, would do the job then. Forget about sessions.